# How to change the default model manager (queryset?) for filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to change the default model manager of django rest framework filter and I can't seem to find a way to do it. My default model manager `objects` excludes some records, I have created `objects_all` for getting all records. filter seems to be using `Model.objects` instead of `objects_all`, is there a way I can somehow make it use `objects_all` so that filtering is possible.

## filters.py

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters

ItemFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.AllLookupsFilter()
    some_id = filters.NumberFilter(name="some_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Item
```

## models.py

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    objects_all = models.Manager() # Rename the default model manager
    objects = ObjectsWithNoStateManager()
    objects_deleted = ObjectsDeletedManager()
    objects_archived = ObjectsArchivedManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add extra filter to your ModelManager. Why don't you just add methods for that extra filter in single ModelManager rather than creating separate manager for each.

Here is the example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods